# Where does your passport get the visa sticker in case of UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk

My question is similar to [this previously asked question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175501/who-actually-does-the-uk-visa-processing). But I'm curious about where does my passport travel to in course of the visa application (does it travel anywhere at all?).

In my case, I applied at Tokyo VAC, and [this link](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/list-of-ukvi-international-application-points-and-decision-making-centres/list-of-ukvi-international-application-points-and-decision-making-centres-accessible-version) tells me my application should have been reviewed in Beijing. But I got an email from *LiverpoolVisaInfo*  instead that my application had "arrived at the UKVI Decision Making Centre". Since the application consists of only digitally uploaded documents, I guess it could go to any decision making centre in the world.

But does my passport get the sticker at the nearest embassy/consulate, or does it go to an centralised location as well

Comment: In 2022 the UK granted 2,836,490 entry clearance visas to people outside the UK. I think it’s highly unlikely that millions of passports get sent around the world; it’s much more likely that the visa vignette is issued by the VAC/embassy where the application was made once the visa processing system alerts them of the decision.

Comment: A VAC doesn't know anything about the application status (issued, refused..., the VAC receives documents from embassies in sealed envelopes), the embassy/HC does. If you watch the UK Border Force episodes in Delhi, the sticker is applied at the HC, it is quite old, but likely still a thing.